# SetTimeout in Angular 8 is ignored

Tags: angular

> When running this code:

```
this.logger.warn('start');
setTimeout(() => {},3000);
delay(3000);
this.logger.warn('start2');
```

> My output says this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NChDU.png)
>
> Blockquote: ngx-logger.js:596 2020-11-19T13:37:40.922Z WARN [10.js:10596] start
> Blockquote: ngx-logger.js:596 2020-11-19T13:37:40.925Z WARN [10.js:10602] start2

So basically my setTimeout gets ignored, same for delay(3000). What could be possible reasons for this? When I check with this.logger it is also ignored.

I am using Angular 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to use `setTimeout` in your example would be like below:

```
this.logger.warn('start');
setTimeout(() => {this.logger.warn('start2')},3000);
```

`delay` is not a valid javascript function

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout()` method works as asynchronous and it does not affect the running time in the main thread.

If you want to wait for some seconds, you can follow this answer.
[What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log('Two seconds later, showing sleep in a loop...');

  // Sleep in loop
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i === 3)
      await sleep(2000);
    console.log(i);
  }
}

demo();
```